# databinding on a user control only working partially (silverlight)

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, user-controls

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I spent a good hour last night to figure it out, maybe I am just dumb.

I created this user control to display a bordered text, which uses data binding to fill the style and the text.

This is how I call it from the main page:

```
<mynamespace:BorderedText x:Name="DateTime"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   BorderStyle="{StaticResource borderStyle}"
                   LabelStyle="{StaticResource labelStyle}"
                   TextStyle="{StaticResource valueStyle}"
                   Label="Current Date/Time"                                           
                   Text="N/A" />
```

The control is pretty simple:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.BorderedText"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="480"
         d:DesignWidth="480">

<Grid>
    <Border Name="border" Style="{Binding BorderStyle}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Style="{Binding LabelStyle}"
                       Text="{Binding Label}" />
            <TextBlock Style="{Binding TextStyle}"
                       Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that all data binding works, except for the Border data binding. I also tried to data bind the background or any other property, without success. 
Code behind has the DependencyProperty properties set up and that’s it. Note that the DataContext for data binding is set up in the constructor. Tried to assign it to the Grid or to the Border itself, without success.
Does anybody have any clue or see something big I am missing here?

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class BorderedText : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Label", typeof(string), typeof(BorderedText), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LabelStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(BorderedText), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(BorderedText), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(BorderedText), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderStyleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BorderStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(BorderedText), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public BorderedText()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ((Grid)this.Content).DataContext = this;
            //((Border)this.Content).DataContext = this;
        }

        public string Label
        {
            set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
            get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        }

        public Style LabelStyle
        {
            set { SetValue(LabelStyleProperty, value); }
            get { return (Style)GetValue(LabelStyleProperty); }
        }

        public string Text
        {
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        }

        public Style TextStyle
        {
            set { SetValue(TextStyleProperty, value); }
            get { return (Style)GetValue(TextStyleProperty); }
        }

        public Style BorderStyle
        {
            set { SetValue(BorderStyleProperty, value); }
            get { return (Style)GetValue(BorderStyleProperty); }
        }
    }
}
```

---- UPDATE:

It turned out to be something completely different and unrelated to databinding which is properly wired...

In the borderStyle I was using this syntax for a background property:

```
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush>
                    <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                        <Color>
                            <Color.A>
                                100
                            </Color.A>
                            <Color.R>#95</Color.R>
                            <Color.B>#ED</Color.B>
                        </Color>
                    </SolidColorBrush.Color>
                </SolidColorBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

which apparently works in the designer but not in the phone.
Changing it to:

```
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#649500ED" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, you forgot one thing... the DataContext of the Border!
Give your UserControl a name, and then you can add to your binding something like:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyText, ElementName=UserControlRoot}" />
```

this will work (at least it worked for me in WPF, heh)

Comment: The DataContext of the border should be defined in the initializer of the usercontrol (neither the commented nor the uncommented one work though). Giving a specific name to the user control does not work, because I need to reuse the usercontrol multiple times in the calling page. If I give a specific name in the usercontrol, when I assign a x:Name to the control in the caller, the data binding breaks again.

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure i follow you..
Why would it a name inside the UserControl effect anything outside of it?
anyway if you don't want a name, you can bind your border/textblocks to RelativeSource Find Ancestor type UserControl.
Furthermore, the datacontext in your initializer doesn't seem right. you are saying that the control is a grid, while it's not. you could do something like: DataContext = this; (i think, didn't test)

Comment: If you name the usercontrol outside with <mycontrol x:name...> what happens is that the name overrides the internal name assigned on the object. So the Binding ElementName="nameassignedinternally" breaks. You can see this happening right in the designer.

Comment: Also, the control has a grid containing the border. At any rate, it turned out to be something completely different.  See update in the question above. Solved!